# Extract a floating point number from a CString

Tags: c++, mfc, cstring

I want to extract a floating point number from a CString formatted as: (example extract 22.760348)

```
Incidence_angle(inc)[deg]                 :22.760348
```

Basically I am reading a plain text file containing some parameters, and I want to perform some calculations on the values. I read the file using a CStdioFile object and extracting each line using the readString method as follows:

```
CStdioFile result(global::resultFile,CFile::modeRead);
while( result.ReadString(tmp) )
            {
                if(tmp.Find(L"Incidence_angle(inc)[deg]") != -1)
                {
                    //extract value of theeta i here
                    // this is probably wrong
                    theeta_i = _tscanf(L"Incidence_angle(inc)[deg]  :%f",&theeta_i);
                }
            }
```

I tried using scanf because I couldnt think of any other way.

I apologize if this question seems very basic and stupid, but I have been stuck on it for a long time and would apppriciate some help.

edit: took out the proof of concept program I wrote, caused confusion

Comment: Could you show a declaration for `theeta_i`?

Comment: @Andrey - float pixel_spacing=0, line_spacing=0, theeta_i=0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `tmp` is `CString`, the correct code is

```
CStdioFile result(global::resultFile,CFile::modeRead);
while( result.ReadString(tmp) )
{
if (swscanf_s(tmp, L"Incidence_angle(inc)[deg]  :%f", &theeta_i) == 1)
    {
        // Use the float falue
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Andrey  
I implemented this. But it never enters the if braces. The condition always evaluates to false. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: CStdioFile result(global::resultFile,CFile::modeRead);
    while( result.ReadString(tmp) )
    {
     if(tmp.Find(L"Incidence_angle(inc)[deg]") != -1)
     {
      //extract value of theeta i 
      if (wscanf_s(tmp, L"Incidence_angle(inc)[deg]                 :%f", &theeta_i) == 1) 
      { 
       // Use the float falue 
       AfxMessageBox(L"Float",0,0);
      } 

     }
    }

Comment: @eternalDreamer: Does it reach sscanf? If it does, please make sure that `"Incidence_angle(inc)[deg]  :"` exactly (including the case and the number of spaces) matches the string you have in the input stream. Also, is that MBCS or Unicode app?

Comment: It reached sscanf. I copied the string exactly from the text file. Its an Unicode app. Im sorry if my lack of knowledge is frustrating you.

Comment: @eternalDreamer Sorry, then you should use the Unicode equivalent of `sscanf`, it is called `swscanf_s` AFAIR

Answer (score 1):

`_tscanf()` returns the number of assignments made, not the value read:

```
theeta_i = _tscanf(L"Incidence_angle(inc)[deg]  :%f",&theeta_i);
```

so `theeta_i` will contain `1`(`.0`) if a `float` was successfully read. Change to:

```
if (1 == _tscanf(L"Incidence_angle(inc)[deg]  :%f",&theeta_i))
{
    /* One float value successfully read. */
}
```

---

That should be `_stscanf()` to read from a buffer, `_tscanf()` will be waiting for input from standard input.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I need to extract the float value, so Il try using this: sscanf_s

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/)?

Example taken from the link:

```
   /* atof example: sine calculator */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main ()
    {
      double n,m;
      double pi=3.1415926535;
      char szInput [256];
      printf ( "Enter degrees: " );
      gets ( szInput );
      n = atof ( szInput );
      m = sin (n*pi/180);
      printf ( "The sine of %f degrees is %f\n" , n, m );
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Its not a console program. Im sorry if my proof of concept program caused a confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it the C++ way altogether?

This is just a hint:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
   double double_val=0.0;
   std::string dump("");
   std::string oneline("str 123.45 67.89 34.567"); //here I created a string containing floating point numbers
   std::istringstream iss(oneline);
   iss>>dump;//Discard the string stuff before the floating point numbers
   while ( iss >> double_val )
   {
      std::cout << "floating point number is = " << double_val << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If you want to use as you have illustrated, using cstring only, try `strtod()` also.
*Source:* `man -s 3 strtod`